# Is there any package required for HTML widgets error?

Tags: r, ggplot2, kaggle

When I try to run plotly graph in Kaggle I get this error.

Error: HTML widgets cannot be represented in plain text (need Html)

Code:

```
 Online_order <- dataset %>% 
      drop_na(online_order) %>%
      dplyr::group_by(online_order) %>% 
      dplyr::summarise(count = n())

Online_order <- plot_ly(Online_order, labels = ~online_order, values = ~count, type = 'pie', marker = list(colors = c("darkred", "darkgreen")))
Online_order <- Online_order %>% 
  layout(title = 'Pie chart for accepting online orders',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

Online_order
```

I am able to view the plot in my Rstudio but not in Kaggle.
I am running the above code in Rmarkdown but not script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called htmlwidgets.

You are missing the package. You are probably trying to knit the output to a HTML file.

Just add the library to the top of your markdown code, don't forget to install it once first.

[CRAN: htmlwidgets package](https://cran.microsoft.com/web/packages/htmlwidgets/index.html)

```
install.packages("htmlwidgets")
```

Then just add it to the top of your markdown code the library as well like so:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
```